# How can I call this native function from F#? (LLVMCreateJITCompilerForModule)

Tags: f#, llvm, dllimport, llvm-c++-api, llvm-fs

I'm using the [llvm-fs](https://github.com/keithshep/llvm-fs/) bindings and one method I would like to call is [`createJITCompilerForModule`](https://github.com/keithshep/llvm-fs/blob/master/src/LLVM/Generated.fs#L5037) which is an extern to the native method [`LLVMCreateJITCompilerForModule`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ExecutionEngineBindings_8cpp_source.html#l00118) in the LLVM C api. The author of llvm-fs has stated he can't make a 'nice' version of this function call in F#:

[`createJITCompilerForModule in llvm-fs:Generated.fs`](https://github.com/keithshep/llvm-fs/blob/master/src/LLVM/Generated.fs#L5037):

```
[<DllImport(
    "LLVM-3.1.dll",
    EntryPoint="LLVMCreateJITCompilerForModule",
    CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)>]
extern bool createJITCompilerForModuleNative(
    void* (* LLVMExecutionEngineRef* *) OutJIT,
    void* (* LLVMModuleRef *) M,
    uint32 OptLevel,
    void* OutError)
// I don't know how to generate an "F# friendly" version of LLVMCreateJITCompilerForModule
```

**Do you know how I would call this function from F#, or even what the native one does?** It looks like it has an 'out parameter' for `OutJIT` (as the native code reassigns a thing the `void*` points to). Here is the native function:

[`LLVMCreateJITCompilerForModule in llvm-c:ExecutionEngineBindings.cpp`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ExecutionEngineBindings_8cpp_source.html#l00118):

```
LLVMBool LLVMCreateJITCompilerForModule(LLVMExecutionEngineRef *OutJIT,
                                        LLVMModuleRef M,
                                        unsigned OptLevel,
                                        char **OutError) {
    std::string Error;
    EngineBuilder builder(unwrap(M));
    builder.setEngineKind(EngineKind::JIT)
           .setErrorStr(&Error)
           .setOptLevel((CodeGenOpt::Level)OptLevel);
    if (ExecutionEngine *JIT = builder.create()) {
        *OutJIT = wrap(JIT);
        return 0;
    }
    *OutError = strdup(Error.c_str());
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling it from F# in the obvious way (just as a normal function)? It seems like everything is correct

Comment: What specifically is your question? What to pass for `void*`? Most likely `nativeint`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual function I wanted to use was a special hand made one as it couldn't be generated. I've put it here as an example of how to call it:

[`llvm-fs:ExecutionEngine.fs`](https://github.com/keithshep/llvm-fs/blob/master/src/LLVM/ExecutionEngine.fs#L17)

```
let private createEngineForModuleFromNativeFunc
        (nativeFunc : (nativeint * nativeint * nativeint) -> bool)
        (moduleRef : ModuleRef) =

    use outEnginePtr = new NativePtrs([|0n|])
    use outErrPtr = new NativePtrs([|0n|])
    let createFailed =
            nativeFunc (
                outEnginePtr.Ptrs,
                moduleRef.Ptr,
                outErrPtr.Ptrs)
    if createFailed then
        let errStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto (Marshal.ReadIntPtr outErrPtr.Ptrs)
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal (Marshal.ReadIntPtr outErrPtr.Ptrs)
        failwith errStr
    else
        ExecutionEngineRef (Marshal.ReadIntPtr outEnginePtr.Ptrs)

let createJITCompilerForModule (modRef : ModuleRef) (optLvl : uint32) =
    let f (engPtr, modPtr, outErrPtr) =
        createJITCompilerForModuleNative (engPtr, modPtr, optLvl, outErrPtr)

    createEngineForModuleFromNativeFunc f modRef
```

Comment: I see you've figured it out yourself. FYI if you hit other bumps there's a better chance that I'll see it at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/llvm-fs